# Searching on array of element using multi threads while element not compared twice

Tags: java, multithreading

I need to find if number entered using console is perfect or not, using Java multi Threading, what i exactly needed is to create a specified number of threads, 
when user enters a number on console, This method checks if it's perfect number  :

```
  int temp 0;

        for (int i = 1; i <= n / 2; i++) {
                int temp = 0;
                if (n % i == 0) {
                    temp += i;

                }
```

i  want each thread created to take a random number from the indexes of the for loop (i)
to check if it's a factor of the number n,While i don't want any factor to be check same time by two different threads, or to be checked twice,
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Creating multi-threaded application to solve your problem is not so easy if you don't use some built-in mechanisms.

But if you decide to do this by yourself I would advice you to create `n` threads implementing `Runnable` interface. Each of which should know its `id` and using this `id` the proper element from array should be taken by the thread and checked - `i-th` thread can take elements `1*i`, `2*i`, ..., `n*i`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tired something like that and i think it worked for me :)